# Why are Christoffel's symbols considered intrinsic

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

This is the *Theorema Egregium of Gauss*.

Gaussian curvature (something defined from derivative of the normal unit vector) depends only from coefficients of the first fundamental form, **so it is intrinsic**. My question is ***"Why"?***

The first fundamental form is given by these three coefficients $E=(\partial_1,\partial_1), F,G$ defined similarly.

Now, we have that $I(v_1\partial_1+v_2\partial_2)=Ev_1^2+2Fv_1v_2 + Gv_2^2$ is independent from the local chart, but its coefficients change. So, ok that $I$ is intrinsic, but why we call also its coefficients intrinsic if they are actually defined from a local chart and depend from the local chart? Why can I call everything which uses only $E,F,G$ to be intrinsic? Why is $E,F,G$ themselves intrinsic?

Comment: Might be helpful: [understanding of the first fundamental form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715628/understanding-of-the-first-fundamental-form)

Comment: See also: [Does intrinsic mean existing regardless of some bigger space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1311173/9464)

Comment: The word "intrinsic" means "having to do only with $I$ and not with the unit normal vector."  The coefficients $E$, $F$, $G$ are intrinsic, yes, but also depend on the local chart.  There is no contradiction in that.  Meanwhile, the definition of Gauss curvature $K$ appears to be extrinsic, yet it is independent of the chart used to compute it.  Once $K$ is expressed in terms of $E$, $F$, $G$ (and their derivatives) alone, we see that $K$ is actually intrinsic.  The formula for $K$ in terms of $E, F, G$ is independent of the local chart, because $K$ is.

Comment: The problem is probably with the meaning (to me) of the word intrinsic in this particular subject. To me (and my textbook) the word intrinsic stands for independence from "how I see the surface in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$. For $I$ there is a good theorem which says that the tangent plane is canonically isomorphic to the derivation space of an equivalence class of smooth functions. So my questions are: Is the word intrinsic has nothing to do with chart independence? Is this the real reason why $I$ is intrinsic?